# How to add different JSON objects to a single array?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON object with the key name `IssuesList` and its value being a JSON array of objects. My problem is that the existing JSON uses two different types of objects in that array. Most instances of `IssuesList` look like this:

```json
    "IssuesList": [
      {
        "IssueOrderNumber": 1,
        "Description": "Houston, we have a problem.",
        "Resolution": "We are working on it.",
        "Severity": 1
      },
      ...
    ]
```

However, there is one special case in which the IssuesList should look like this:

```json
    "IssuesList": [
      {
        "EventDate": "2023-12-20",
        "RecordClassificationTypeSelected": "In-patient hospitalization for medical treatment",
        "InjuryIllnessDescription": null
      },
      ...
    ]
```

Right now, the following code won't compile because the issue parameter is of the wrong type in the special case.

```
public int AddToIssuesList(string companyid, string templateid, string pageid, int metadatatypeid, string requestorId, IssuesList issue)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string wholeJsonData = PageDataRequiringValidation(metadatatypeid, null, null, null, companyid, requestorId);
            var objWholeJsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(wholeJsonData);
            var objPage = objWholeJsonData.Pages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageId == pageid);
            objPage.PageData.IssuesList.Add(issue);
            var updatedWholeJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objWholeJsonData);
            // TODO: Write to DB
            return 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And here are my models:

```
public class IssuesList
{
    public int IssueOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; } = null;
}

public class OSHAIncidentsList
{
    [JsonProperty("IssuesList")]
    public string EventDate { get; set; }
    public string RecordClassificationTypeSelected { get; set; }
    public string InjuryIllnessDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I'm seeing if I can pass in a flag from the front end to put a branch in the code to deserialize the issue parameter in different ways. Is there a better way to handle these two different models? TIA!

Comment: If you have a impact for JSON then it is best to have 2 list names for separate types.

Comment: Can the `IssueOrderNumber` and `EventDate` both appear at the same time, or will it be all one or all the other? And do you know in advance which it will be?

Comment: Will Severity be int or string? Its a string in your Model but a int in your JSON

Comment: Do you just need something to be able to Serialize, or do you need it to properly Deserialize as well?

Comment: Severity will be a string. IssueOrderNumber and EventDate cannot appear at the same time. There is a value higher up in the JSON that will determine which set of values will appear here. I'll need to both serialize and deserialize.

Comment: please confirm that response list will /might contain both types in same list or ieach response will contain list of one type

Answer (score 0):

as i assume list might contain both structures in same json. i would propose this approach to deserialize to list of tuples (one of classes would be null)
idea behins is to look for class property which unique to one class, means if  not exists - deserialize to other class.

```
void Main()
{
    var lst = new List<(IssuesList, OSHAIncidentsList)>();
    
    var json = "{\"IssuesList\":[{\"IssueOrderNumber\":1,\"Description\":\"Houston, we have a problem.\",\"Resolution\":\"We are working on it.\",\"Severity\":1},{\"EventDate\":\"2023-12-20\",\"RecordClassificationTypeSelected\":\"In-patient hospitalization for medical treatment\",\"InjuryIllnessDescription\":null}]}";
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ROOT>(json).IssuesList
    .ForEach(item => 
    {
        lst.Add(GetClassSet(item));
    });
    lst.Dump();
}

public (IssuesList, OSHAIncidentsList) GetClassSet(JObject res){
    if (res.First.ToObject<JProperty>().Name.ToUpper() == "ISSUEORDERNUMBER")
        return(res.ToObject<IssuesList>(), null);
    else
        return (null, res.ToObject<OSHAIncidentsList>());
}

public class ROOT { 
    public List<JObject> IssuesList {get;set;}
    public ROOT(){IssuesList = new List<JObject>();}
}

public class IssuesList
{
    public int IssueOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; } = null;
}

public class OSHAIncidentsList
{
    public string EventDate { get; set; }
    public string RecordClassificationTypeSelected { get; set; }
    public string InjuryIllnessDescription { get; set; }
}
```

as a result would be (to complex to convert to text)
[image]